# Updating a registration form without refreshing a page

Tags: php, html

I'm designing a registration form in PHP using html. The form collects personal info from users some fields include the marital status, name of spouse, and the number of children. How can I code it such that whenever a user selects "Single" for his/her marital status, the textboxes for the name of spouse and number of children will be automatically disabled? All of this must be done without refreshing the page. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use ajax for that.

Comment: Those things are done with JavaScript.  No need to refresh page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using drop down for marital status, use the `onchange` event to capture the change in the drop down status

```
function maritalStatusChange()
{
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("maritalstatus").value;
    if(dropdown == 'Single')
    {
        document.getElementById("spousefld").readOnly = "readonly";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using the javascript function.

if you have used combobox for marrital status

```
<select id="a" onchange="if( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=='s')
{document.getElementById('spouce').readOnly = true;}
">
    <option value='s'>single</option>
    <option value='m'>married</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='spouce'/>
```

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hemant1027/JNXws/1/)

Comment: check the implementation in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS for your purpose.
Try this code : (Assuming "single" is your radio button)

```
if (document.geElementById('maritalStatus').checked){
   //disable resp textboxes
   document.geElementById('spouce').disabled = true;
   document.geElementById('children').disabled = true;
}
```

for more details [see this](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript/enable_disable_form_element.asp)